# Python Pip not installing package into the correct directory in virtual environment Visual Studio for Mac - "unresolved import"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, python-venv

EDIT: See **WORKAROUND** in reply - if you get "unresolved import" on a package you have installed this might be the reason.

Even though VScode settings are set to use the venv interpreter, and the virtual environment is activated, when using pip or pip3 to install a package in the VSCode terminal, packages are installed into the default python directory.

e.g.

> `(.venv) person@MacBook-Pro my-code-lives-here % pip3 install python-dotenv`

results after trying it twice so you can see the install path:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.15.0)
```

VS code settings.json:

> `"python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python3",`

Same command was working last week as I have other packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

**WORKAROUND**

use pip's --target arg to specify the site-packages dir of the virutal environment:

e.g

> `pip3 install --target=/<path-to-code-folder>/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages python-dotenv`

Comment: Can't we set the target path permanently or do we have to define everytime we install a package?